# How can I add the log into a jqgrid column?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Here is the sample code I'm trying.

```
{
        name : 'scopeName',
        index : 'scopeName',
        width: '400px',
        resizable : true,
        align : "left",
        editable : true,
        edittype : "select",
        editoptions : {
            value : getSequenceNumbers()
        },
        editrules : {
            required : true
        }

function:

    function getSequenceNumbers() {
        alert("here123");
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8039/ReleaseManagementApp/releasemgmt/config/Q2FY16/scope", null, function(data) {
        if (data != null) {
            alert("here");
            //construct string.  
            //(or the server could return a string directly)
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].scopeName + '">' + data[i].scopeName + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the json data from [server-link](http://localhost:8039/ReleaseManagementApp/releasemgmt/config/Q2FY16/scope).

```
data:
[
  {
    "scopeId": 101,
    "scopeName": "FCM Attributes to be captured in CG1 OM",
    "scopeDesc": "New Attributes to be captured in FCM",
    "scopeIdentifier": "Q2FY16_FCM_Attributes_to_be_ca"
  },
  {
    "scopeId": 104,
    "scopeName": "PBI000000043281",
    "scopeDesc": "OMLSS-OM-Production Bug- Workflow-Line Workflow purged even before Line is closed",
    "scopeIdentifier": "FY16_OCT_MR_PBI000000043281"
  },
  {
    "scopeId": 106,
    "scopeName": "PBI000000049219",
    "scopeDesc": "AS-T Inbound and re-process program issues",
    "scopeIdentifier": "FY16_OCT_MR_PBI000000049219"
  }
]
```

I want to know if I can populate the scopeName from above response into a jqgrid as a select tab.

Answer (score 0):

Instead i suggest you to use custom formatter for this:

```
{
    name : 'scopeName',
    index : 'scopeName',
    width: '400px',
    resizable : true,
    align : "left",
    formatter:getSequenceNumbers // <----use the function here
}
```

now you can return a select element from this function:

```
function getSequenceNumbers() {
        alert("here123");
        var sel = '<select>';
            sel +='<option value="select">Select...</option>';
        $.getJSON("url", null, function(data) {
        if (data != null) {
            alert("here");
            //construct string.  
            //(or the server could return a string directly)
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                sel += '<option value="' + data[i].scopeName + '">' 
                        + data[i].scopeName + '</option>';
            }
            sel +="</select>";
        }
    });
    return sel;
}
```